# How can I clear the focus from a desensitized GtkWidget - GtkSpinButton with property sensitive = false

Tags: c++, gtk

Background: I have a few tabs set up in my `GtkNotebook`, and when certain conditions are met on the main tab, then input fields in the 'test signals' tab are accordingly disabled.

When the input inside a `GtkSpinButton` is highlighted on the 'test signals' tab and the `GtkSpinButton`'s property `sensitive` is set to `false`, the text within the `GtkSpinButton` remains highlighted. Because sometimes there are no other editable fields on this tab, the text remains highlighted until another widget has its property `sensitive` set to `true`.

This just looks sloppy to me, so I would like to stop this behavior and have the widgets that are set to `sensitive` = `false` all cleared of focus or highlighting. Any idea how to un-highlight the text within the `GtkSpinButton`, maybe before setting `sensitive` = `false`?

Comment: Look at `gtk_editable_select_region()`.

Comment: That was it, casted the spin button to GtkEditable and selected from 0 to 0. Thank you very much, if you throw it up there as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of a selection you can use the `gtk_editable_select_region()` function. This is a method on GtkEditable, an interface that both GtkEntry and GtkSpinButton satisfy. You can convert either of these to GtkEditable with `GTK_EDITABLE()`. For example:

```
gtk_editable_select_region(GTK_EDITABLE(spinbutton), 0, 0);
```